# How to filter out ANSI escape sequences from bash read command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How to get user input, filtering out garbage characters while retaining basic line editing?

Using bash scripting, I got to display a long EULA which typically will get mouse-scrolled-down or paged-downed.

Following the EULA message is a typical 'read' command which typically gets polluted with ANSI escape sequences --- from mouse usage or PG-UP,DOWN,HOME keys.

I don't want to use 'read -e' which uses readline as the edit line will get history entries a mouse gets scrolled up or down.

I'm trying a char-by-char input from the bash 'read' command but it's tedious and complicated. Then if I want to preserve minimal editing I have to add a basic state. Finally, because of the possible ANSI escape sequences ( that might come form scrolling the mouse for example ) I would need to implement some state machine waiting for ^[.. until completion of command still allowing normal alpha-numeric

Isn't there something out-of-the box to properly handle a clean user input?

Comment: can you post an example of input ?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to explain and I apologize for my bad English. Still, you can simply try the following:

`
$ read $input
`

Without pressing the enter key, try the mouse or page-up,down, home keys. You will get such characters:

`
^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B
`

Comment: @Rastikan there's not much you can easily do about that, I'm afraid. ^[[B is just escape (which is an ASCII character) followed by [ and then B, neither of which are control characters. It's probably more work than it's worth trying to filter these out.

Comment: Use `dialog` or `whiptail` or whatever similar tool is handy.